# How do I search ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) data with the conditional logic?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

All,

I'm running a search with Wordpress and it's returning ACF data. The problem, is that for fields that are hidden with conditional logic, they are still returning in the search results.

Does anyone happen to know how to exclude fields that are hidden? Or, does anyone know those items are declared as hidden in the database? I can't seem to find anything that ties a field to another in the wp_postmeta.

EDIT: added some code by request

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
global $query_string;
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
}
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$search = new WP_Query(
        $search_query,
        array( 
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_status'=>'publish', 
            'post__in' => array(),
            //'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => $paged 
        )
    );
$resultArray = array();
    if (have_posts()){
        while(have_posts()): the_post();
            //places the WP post meta data into an array
            $array  = get_post_meta($post->ID);
            //Flattens the array into one-dimensonal
            $result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
            //changes the search term to all lower case
            $searchword = strtolower($search_query['s']);
            //Searches the $result array for the $searchword and saves all occurances into $matches array
            $matches = array_filter($result, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", strip_tags($var)); });
            //Grab the first value of the $matches array since we won't always know the key
            $first_value = reset($matches);

            if(!empty($first_value)){
                array_push($resultArray,
                    array(
                        'id'=>$post->ID,
                        'match' =>strip_tags($first_value)
                    )
                );
            }
        endwhile;
    }
   $total_results = count($resultArray); 
?>
```

Comment: can you post some sample code?

Comment: I've added our search code. For the most part, we add the post_meta to the search. However, I don't see a way to differentiate fields that are hidden.